# Plane-plane intersection line

Tags: vectors, plane-geometry

If I have a plane $A$ defined in the form $r \cdot n = 0$ and another plane $B: z = 7$, if I substitute $z=7$ into the first plane's equation , am I finding a point that lies on both planes or is it the equation or direction of the line that the planes form when they intersect?

I know that the cross product of the normals of both planes give the direction of the intersecting line but I'm really confused. What exactly am I getting when I substitute the plane $B: z=7$ into plane $A$'s equation?

Answer (score 1):

$z=7$ is a plane. $\Bbb{A}$ is also a plane.

So when you substitute $z=7$ in $\Bbb{A}$, you get the locus of **all the points** that are common to both the planes. i.e. a line

Comment: What's the difference between the general line $a + \lambda d$ and this line?

Comment: @Nubcake ABSOLUTELY **nothing**. In fact you will find $a,\lambda\ \&\ d$ from substituting $z=7$.